# How do I subscribe to a reactive streams implementation running on a different JVM?

Tags: jvm, akka-stream, reactive-streams

Let's assume we have two Akka Stream flows, each running on its own JVM.

```
// A reactive streams publisher running on JVM 1:
val stringPublisher: Publisher[String] = Source(() => "Lorem Ipsum".split("\\s").iterator).runWith(Sink.publisher[String])

// A reactive streams subscriber running on JVM 2:
def subscriber: Subscriber[String] = Sink.foreach[String](println(_)).runWith(Source.subscriber[String])

// Subscribe the second stream to the first stream
stringPublisher.subscribe(subscriber)
```

This example runs fine on one JVM, but how can I subscribe to a publisher running on a different JVM?

Do I have to use messaging/queueing middleware or can I use the reactive streams API to connect the two together?

Comment: on first sight, i would say you will need some messaging or RPC, since each JVM runs on its own sandbox

Comment: Good question... I'm also reasoning about "distributed reactive streams". The underlying mechansim is Akka, and Akka scales out to different machines. But I'm not sure if Akka-Stream supports this "out-of-the-box"...

Answer (score 3):

The [reactive-streams](http://reactive-streams.org) spec does not speak about distributed (crossing network) streams, and none of the current implementations of it (Akka Streams as an example) implement streams that cross network boundaries. It's a bit tricky to do (but can be done and possibly will be) as it requires transparent re-delivery in case of message loss.

Short answer: you (currently) can't. However since Akka HTTP is stream based and applies back-pressure via TCP you can connect streams via [stream based TCP or HTTP](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-stream-and-http-experimental/1.0-RC3/scala/stream-io.html) and the back-pressure will work as expected.